# Conectar formularios

Tags: django

tengo un formulario el cual trabaja bien, pero quiero que cuando termine de ingresar datos y le de a registrar este me envie a otro formulario para anexar información.

Este es mi formulario:
formulario.html:_

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Django | Formulario {% endblock %}

{% block Contenido %}
<body style="background-color:rgb(212, 224, 224);">
  </body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row main">
                <div class="main-login main-center">
          {% if object %}
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ request.path }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% else %}
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ request.path }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% endif %}
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.nombre }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="apellidos" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Apellidos</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.apellidos }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ci" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Cedula de identidad</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.ci }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="genero" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Genero</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.genero }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cargo" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Cargo actual</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.cargo }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Correo Electronico</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.email}}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telefono" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Telefono</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.telefono }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="documento" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Archivo</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.documento }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <input class="{% if object %}btn btn-success {% else %} btn btn-primary {% endif %} btn-lg btn-block login-button" type="submit" name="Registrar" value="{% if object %} Editar {% else %} Registrar {% endif %}">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <hr />
</div>

{% endblock Contenido %}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

y este seria el otro formulario:
formulariopersonal.html:

{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Django | Formulario {% endblock %}

{% block Contenido %}
<body style="background-color:rgb(212, 224, 224);">
  </body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row main">
                <div class="main-login main-center">
          {% if object %}
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ request.path }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% else %}
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ request.path }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% endif %}
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="direccion" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Direccion</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.direccion }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="estado_civil" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Estado civil</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.estado_civil }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="grado_instruccion" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Grado de instruccion</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.grado_intruccion }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="numero_de_hijos" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Numero de hijos</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.numero_de_hijos }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>              
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <input class="{% if object %}btn btn-success {% else %} btn btn-primary {% endif %} btn-lg btn-block login-button" type="submit" name="Registrar" value="{% if object %} Editar {% else %} Registrar {% endif %}">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <hr />
</div>

{% endblock Contenido %}
```

estuve revisando mis forms.py y mi modelo y al parecer no tengo nada malo ya que cuando reviso este me esta guardando los dato que recibe en el primer formulario pero no me deja ingresar al segundo para agregar mas información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una vez hayas ingresado los datos del primer formulario haz un render en la view que te redirija hacia la view del segundo formulario y a su template asociado. Rellena el formulario y trátalo como hiciste con el primero. En principio no debería darte muchos problemas..